# Windows Kiosk mode: open 'Desktop'

Tags: windows, kiosk

With Windows 11 Kiosk mode with Edge, the user can't upload files, with an error:

> Can't open this location
> We can't open 'Desktop'. To help keep your data safe, the location is blocked.

An `Administrator` account, can use the locally deployed web application, to select and upload files.

Is there a way to configure the Kiosk user to allow uploading files, or restrict the folder to some specific location?

Comment: I suspect this has less to do with Edge being in Kiosk mode rather Controlled folder access being enabled or some other security software at play.  Do you have Controlled Folder access enabled by chance?

Comment: How are you uploading the files ?

Comment: The files are being uploaded by a web application (made with Flutter). The admin user can use the application and selects/uploads files fine, but not with the Kiosk user.